# What's a good way to get items quickly?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have always wondered what I should do to get items quickly in TF2 without paying any money?

Comment: Besides what he said, you can purchase items (usually not worth it). But, if you become premium, the drop limit increases (I forget in what way). Then, if you have premium, you can trade items you don't want for items you do. For your first purchase I would recommend a key, seeing that A- You can unbox, and B- You can easily trade it for good stuff.

Comment: Be polite on a server and you can often find someone willing to give you a weapon for free.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Items are dropped randomly when playing, at the rate of approximately 1 per hour, over a maximum of 10 hours of play per week. There is no way to increase this.

You also receive items from completing the Milestone achievements- the "Earn x class achievements" achievements. There are 3 achievements per class which typically provide you with one weapon for each slot.

Trading is also possible, though if you haven't spent any money you can only receive items- you cannot give them.

Answer (score -3):

You can get between 8-14 (most oftenly around 10) items each week. It always resets on Thursdays, so you have the possibility of getting more items on that day.